# Paste the content of many columns together in data.table without specifying them manually

Tags: r, data.table

I have a character vector of column names and I want the content of these columns pasted together as a new character vector in a data table. Manually this is easy:

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.table(a = "here", b = 1, c = "example")
```

and I can specify them as characters and use get():

```
mydata[, d := paste0(get("a"), get("b"), get("c"))]
```

but I don't know how to get there from a vector of column names:

```
mycols <- names(mydata)[1:3]
```

Here my attempts:

```
> mydata[, d := paste0(get(mycols))]
Error in get(mycols) : first argument has length > 1

> mydata[, d := paste0(eval(paste0("get(",mycols,")")))]
Error in `[.data.table`(mydata, , `:=`(d, paste0(eval(paste0("get(", mycols,  : 
Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'd'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

In reality I have many columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.SDcols` with `do.call()`:

```
mydata[, e := do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = mycols]
```

Comment: could you explain how this works? Both .SDcols and do.call sound like Vodoo...

Comment: If you read [`?data.table`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html), it describes `.SDcols` as the columns of `x` to be included in the special symbol `.SD`; and see [`?special-symbols`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/special-symbols.html) (perhaps not intuitive) for what `.SD` means (in short: `S`ubset of x's `D`ata).

Comment: `do.call` is base R, it is a way to programmatically call a function with an arbitrary set of arguments (including none). It is a skosh of "meta-programming". In this case, we don't necessarily know how many columns are involved, and don't want to program them all individually. If we have three columns in `mycols`, then this is equivalent to `paste(x[[mycols[1]]], x[[mycols[2]]], x[[mycols[3]]])`; if two in `mycols`, then it's equivalent to `paste(x[[mycols[1]]], x[[mycols[2]]])`, but without needing to change any code to be flexible to the number of columns.